# Почему Setprecision округляет по другому?

Tags: c++

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << -3.25 << "\n";
```

```
cout << fixed << round(-3.25*10)/10 << "\n";
```

выводит разные результаты. Как это исправить? Какие еще есть варианты вывести определенное количество знаков после запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setprecision` не округляет числа, он устанавливает точность вывода чисел с плавающей точкой в поток вывода, т.е. количество знаков после десятичной точки. Округление чисел происходит в функциях `round()`, `floor()`.

Для того, чтобы правильно округлять числа при выводе, нужно использовать соответствующую функцию округления, например, `round()`, и задавать нужную точность вывода с помощью функции `setprecision()`. Если установленная точность не совпадает с фактическим числом знаков после десятичной точки, то результат округления может отличаться от ожидаемого. Например, если задать точность вывода в 1 знак после десятичной точки, то число 3.25 будет выведено как 3.2, а не как 3.3, как при использовании функции `round()`.

Answer (score -1):

Есть такой вот простой вариант, который не округляет вовсе ничего, просто пишет ровно столько знаков, сколько вы зададите вместо цифры "9":

```
printf("%.9f", -3.25);
```

Вообще есть ещё вариант писать `std::ceil` и `std::floor`, в зависимости, куда вам надо округлить. `std::setprecision` округляет предыдущую цифру по последующей, насколько я понял по своим экспериментам. В документации не написана логика округления.

Если хотите вывести одну цифру после запятой - используйте `printf("%.1f", -3.25);`

Можете допустим так же в строку перевести `std::to_string(-3.25)`

и потом её выводить до одного символа после запятой (или точки, по идеи там будет точка как разделитель).